# Can somone admit to being a invalid witness?

Tags: halacha, edim-witnesses

If somone admits that they are a invalid witness do we believe them? Does it matter whether they're saying they're invalid because of a Aveira or a bad midda?

Comment: Check out the rule אין אדם משים עצמו רשע

Comment: As I mentioned on your other question on the topic, the list of pesulim is in Sanhedrin 3:3 for reference.

Comment: Even if he's not believed, a follow up question would be, Should he act as a witness when he knows that he has committed aveiros that would invalidate him, had there been witnesses? The beis din will accept him, but should he reject himself?

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam Hilchot Edut 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Testimony.12.2?lang=bi)

> ‫אֵין אָדָם נִפְסָל בַּעֲבֵרָה עַל פִּי עַצְמוֹ. כֵּיצַד. הֲרֵי שֶׁבָּא לְבֵית דִּין וְאָמַר שֶׁגָּנַב אוֹ גָּזַל אוֹ הִלְוָה בְּרִבִּית. אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמְּשַׁלֵּם עַל פִּי עַצְמוֹ אֵינוֹ נִפְסָל. וְכֵן אִם אָמַר שֶׁאָכַל נְבֵלָה אוֹ בָּעַל אֲסוּרָה אֵינוֹ נִפְסָל עַד שֶׁיִּהְיוּ שָׁם שְׁנֵי עֵדִים שֶׁאֵין אָדָם מֵשִׂים אֶת עַצְמוֹ רָשָׁע.
>
> A person does not become invalid [to testify] through committing a sin on his own testimony. How so? Someone comes to court and admits to burglary or robbery or to lending with interest, even though he has to repay based on his admission, he does not become invalid [to testify]. Similarly, if he admits to eating *neveilah* or having sexual relations with one forbidden to him, he does not become invalid unless there are two witnesses [to his crime], because a person cannot deem himself to be wicked.